# Is there any easy way to make a method/program rerun after a speffic button press?

Tags: java

I wrote a simple, low-level randomizer that creates a character for a board game that my friends and I play. However, after writing it, I realized that I also needed an easy way to rerun the program in order to generate a new random character. Currently, I must close the program and then rerun it in order to generate a new character. Is there any simple way to do this? Please note that I am a rather intermediate coder.

I've searched the Web and most of the solutions that I found require creating a GUI. That is something I would prefer not to do. I've also tried using a `while` loop as a solution but I haven't found a way to pause the program until a button is pressed.

Anything simple would be appreciated. If I must do something more complex, like creating a GUI, I am prepared to learn how to.

Comment: Modified the wording of the question text in an attempt to make it clearer. You should also post your code because that would help others to help you with it. Posting your code would also help understand what you are trying to do. Posting the name of the game you are writing the code for may also be helpful. If you haven't already done so, I recommend reading [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

There are two solutions to your problem. Using a for loop and using a while loop.

A for loop will run a block of code x amount of times. e.g.

```
    System.out.println("How many characters would you like? ");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int result = scanner.nextInt();

    for (int i = 0; i < result; i++) {
        // Code to give user a character runs "result" amount of times
    }
```

A while loop will run indefinitely until a condition is met. e.g.

```
    boolean anotherCharacter = true;
    while (anotherCharacter) {
        // Code to give user a character runs until "anotherCharacter" is false

        System.out.println("Would you like another character? (yes/no) ");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String result = scanner.next();

        if (result.equalsIgnoreCase("no")) {
            anotherCharacter = false;
        }
    }
```

In your situation, the best option to choose depends on whether or not you know exactly how many characters you want at the start of the game. If so, I would recommend the for loop. However, if you do not know the number of characters at the start of the game, I would recommend the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution I see is with your while loop, to ask between characters « do you wish to continue » with a yes/no answer. This way your program would wait between executions.
You could then wrap your character making logic inside that while loop.
Googling for « java input » would help you there.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you wanted to execute a code until a specific key is pressed(and not a button which will only be available in the case of a GUI). This wont be possible unless you implement it using native libraries. You can go through JNI or JNA docs to accomplish this. It would be much simpler to use GUI's though, and will be platform independent unlike in the case of native libraries.

[JnativeHook](https://github.com/kwhat/jnativehook) can be used to implement the functionality that you are looking for using native libraries.